# Area between $y = 5+x-x^2$ and $y = x+4$

Tags: calculus, integration, area

I have the following 2 equations and I have drawn their graphs.

$$\begin{cases}y=5+x-x^2\\
y=x+4\end{cases}$$

I have found intercepts as well.

The question is asking to find area between these 2 curves. I am not sure if I should take as a whole triangle?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can get integration out of the subtraction of the two functions.
integrate (ax^2+bx+c)-(x+4)

Comment: I have tried solving. The equations are 5+x-x^2 and x+4. I have found area n its -56. I think its wrong. I m not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The shaded area is the area between $(5+x-x^2)$ and $x+4$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}(5+x-x^2-x-4)\ dx=\frac43$$
[image]